# Return results and include sub-summary by variable

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I would like to sub-summarize the DISTINCT data returned by the id_module variable and display the id_content and the title as well.

I have tried using array_sum, array_count and for_each... I am struggling to understand how to set this up correctly.  I have gotten part of it to work and am looking for direction on how to get the rest of the data to show.

Here is a sample of the JSON array I am able to retrieve when I perform the following query:

```
 select DISTINCT id_module, id_cr, title from content WHERE (id_module = '003' OR id_module = '005')  
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DISTINCT id_module, id_cr, title FROM content_users WHERE (id_module = '003' OR id_module = '005') and id_user='999'

 Array
    (
         [content] => Array
             (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                         [id_content] => 49620
                         [title] => Asthma: The Basics—Part 1
                         [id_module] => 001
                     )
                 [1] => Array
                     (
                         [id_content] => 49633
                         [title] => Asthma: The Basics—Part 2
                         [id_module] => 001
                     )
                 [2] => Array
                     (
                         [id_content] => 48469
                         [title] => Autism Spectrum Disorder
                         [id_module] => 002
                     )
               )
       )
```

This is the query I am using to return the summarized results (id_module may have duplicates, so I only want the DISTINCT modules so the count is correct).  This query works fine and returns what I expect:

```
select id_module, count(id_module) as total_module from 
    (
    select DISTINCT id_module, id_cr, title from content WHERE (id_module = '003' OR id_module = '005')  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT id_module, id_cr, title FROM content_users WHERE (id_module = '003' OR id_module = '005') and id_user='999'
)
as T GROUP BY id_module ORDER BY id_module
```

The results returned are:

```
id_module     total_module
  001              2
  002              1
```

What I also need to happen is to have both the results of both queries combined... the id_content and the title returned with the summary... something like this, but I have not been successful in writing a query that will return in this format:

```
id_module     total_module     id_content     title
  001              2              49620       Asthma: The Basics—Part 1
  001              2              49633       Asthma: The Basics—Part 2     
  002              1              48469       Autism Spectrum Disorder
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?  I am grateful for any advice or direction - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the two queries on the `id_module` column.

```
SELECT t1.id_module, t2.total_module, t1.id_cr, t1.title
FROM (
    select DISTINCT id_module, id_cr, title from content WHERE id_module IN ('003', '005')  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT id_module, id_cr, title FROM content_users WHERE id_module IN ('003', '005') and id_user='999'
) AS t1 
JOIN (
    SELECT id_module, COUNT(*) AS total_module
    FROM (
        select DISTINCT id_module, id_cr, title from content WHERE id_module IN ('003', '005')  
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT id_module, id_cr, title FROM content_users WHERE id_module IN ('003', '005') and id_user='999'
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY id_module
) AS t2 ON t1.id_module = t2.id_module
ORDER BY t1.id_module
```

It's also generally better to use `id_module IN (x, y, z, ...)` rather than `id_module = x OR id_module = y OR id_module = z ...`. And use `COUNT(*)` unless you need to ignore null values in your count.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.  I tried it and am getting the following error... Column 'T.id_module' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry, left out the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thanks for adding it - works great - thank you so much for helping me with this and for the advice above, both are very appreciated!